# How do I become proficient with the terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

As a programming novice, I often run into trouble when trying to install packages, use virtualenv, and basically do anything even mildly complex using the command line.

What are some good references out there to help me UNDERSTAND things like my path, environment, shell scripts, etc?

Basically, I'm tired of copying and pasting.  I want to really understand what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Linux in a Nutshell](http://amzn.to/OfNUJP) by O'Reilly. It helps you get past the initial beginners stage. Obviously there are a ton more links and tutorials, lists of keystrokes online, easily found with a Google search, but this will help you get going, and nice to read when you are on the bus or at lunch or whatever, to give you some ideas you might not just happen on in normal everyday life.